# left eigenvector as unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following equation in linear algebra:
$\ \lambda·x·y-(x·M·y)=0$ , with $\ x$ and $\ y$ being respectively  1xn and nx1 vectors, and $\ M$ a nxn real semipositive  and irreducible matrix. Also vector $\ y$ is real semipositive (but not one of the right eigenvectors of $\ M$), while $\lambda$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $\ M$. My aim is to find vector $\ x$. Certainly, from what I can see, apart the trivial one, a solution is the dominant left eigenvector of $\ M$. The question I ask if it is the only non trivial solution or if other solutions are also possibile.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector  $y$ is real semipositive"?

Comment: vector $\ y$: its elements are real positive numbers,  with possibly some zeros. The latter - if present - should be placed as such that also $\  M·y $ is also a semipositive vector.